# Understanding a simple regex

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, symfony

I am developing a Symfony2 PHP application. In my Wamp server, the application is stored in `www/mySite/` and my index.php is `www/mySite/web/app_dev.php`. Because/ of that, I have URL like `127.0.0.1/mySite/web/app_dev.php`

I wanted to change the path so I acces my index file just by typing 127.0.0.1. After some research, I figured out that writting this .htacces in the www folder works :

```
RewriteEngine on
Rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mySite
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ /mySite/web/app_dev.php
```

The only problem is that I don't understand why. Does somebody explain it to me ?
I don't really understand the two last line, and regex like `^(.*)$`

Thanks

Comment: means `any number of charachters for any number of times, goes to /mySite/web/app_dev.php`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a simple regex indeed:

```
^(.*)$
```

Let's break it up:

- `^` - begging of a string
- `(` and `)` - capture group, used to match part of a string
- `.` - any character
- `.*` - any charactery any number of times
- `$` - end of a string

So, putting it all together, it means: "match any number of any characters". Later this matched part (part in parentheses) is replaced by `/mySite/web/app_dev.php`.

To explain regexes a little bit more we could imagine different regexes:

- `^lorem.*$` - string starting with word "lorem" followed by any number of any characters
- `^$` - an empty string
- `^...$` - a string containing three characters.

---

Now, putting it all together - Apache's rewrite rules are usually built of two directives: `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule`. The latter directive will affect only those requests which match the condition given in the `RewriteCond`. You can think of them as a "if-then" pair:

```
# the "if" part - if request URI does not match ^/mySite
Rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mySite

# the "then" part - then rewrite it to "/mySite/web/app_dev.php"
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ /mySite/web/app_dev.php
```

Comment: Ok, but I don't understand why if I remove the Rewritecond then it doesn't work ?

Comment: @user2108742 - from the mod_rewrite [doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule): "If you wish to match against the full URL-path in a per-directory (htaccess) RewriteRule, use the %{REQUEST_URI} variable in a RewriteCond."

Comment: Ok, so now if I go to 127.0.0.1 it redirects me to 127.0.0.1/mySite/web/app_dev.php. Fine. But if I type 127.0.0.1/homePage.php, it redirect me to 127.0.0.1/mySite/web/app_dev.php/homePage.php. It's fine too, but I don't understand why. I thought it would redirect everything ^(.*)$ to the app_dev.php. So how could it be redirect to app_dev.php/homePage.php ?

Comment: @user2108742 - it shouldn't behave this way. Try adding `[R=301,L]` at the end of your rule, i.e.: `Rewriterule ^(.*)$ /mySite/web/app_dev.php [R=301,L]`

Comment: R=301 redirect me to the full real path indeed. This is great, but I would like to keep the url clean like juste 127.0.0.1/home.php. How can I do that ?

Comment: @kamituel i like "if-then" explanation ;) More easier to understand.

Answer (score 3):

```
Rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mySite
```

Check and make sure the requested uri does not("!") start with("^") "/mySite"

```
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ /mySite/web/app_dev.php
```

Then if that is true, take things starting with("^") any character(".") any amount of times("*") and send it to "/mySite/web/app_dev.php"

So a URI of /controller/site-action will be sent to that file while /mySite/css/style.css would not be.

Answer (score 0):

Many places to check that will give a breakdown and explanation: http://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions work character after character. In your `.htaccess it checks if the current URI matches the regex. In this image, follow the line character after character and it returns true:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

`^` and `$` stand for the beginning and end of a string.
`.` allows any character and `*` tells to "repeat the last rule as often as possible".